# Location.getLatitude() & location.getLongitude not giving decimals

Tags: android, gps

So I'm making an app that calculates the distance between your position (Point 1) and another specified position (Point 2) through GPS.

The issue I'm having is that the functions `location.getLatitude()` and `location.getLongitude()` don't seem to output any decimals.

Here's my code:

```
Location locationA = new Location("point A");

            locationA.setLatitude(52.44530); //Point 1 coords
            locationA.setLongitude(19.02886);


            Location locationB = new Location("point B");

            locationB.setLatitude(location.getLatitude()); //Point 2 coords
            locationB.setLongitude(location.getLongitude());

            float distance = locationA.distanceTo(locationB);
            textView.append("\n "+distance);
```

`LocationA` works, where I set it manually using `location.setLatitude()` (I'm also able to set `LocationB` in the same way) however when i use `Android Device Manager` to input a manual `GPS` location that `location.getLatitude()` will use, it only outputs eg. 52.00000.